# Click event not working on a div appended dynamically in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using jquery geocomplete plugin to show address suggestion when user type any address. It appends one div dynamically having class "pac-container". It looks like this :

```
<div class="pac-container">
    <div class="pac-item"><b>SDG</b>, Vaishali, Bihar, India</div>
    <div class="pac-item"><b>SDG</b>M, Kuber Nagar, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India</div>
    <div class="pac-item"><b>sdg</b>sdf, Isselburg, Germany</div>
    <div class="pac-item">Lorong <b>Sdg</b> Kasim B Hamid Malacca Melaka Malaysia</div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is when I click on any of the pac-item I have to stop event bubbling. How can I attach the event handler on dynamically added pac-item for IE.

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EcPdP/2/

It is working fine for all browser except IE. In IE, clicking on pac-item is propagating that click event to body. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: what IE version are you using?

Comment: Sorry but i cannot reproduce your issue here

Comment: Make sure you append the event AFTER the element exists in the DOM or it won't work.. I couldn't reproduce the issue either I might add - based on your fiddle.

Comment: Check updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EcPdP/4/... I have just commented out `console.log` and it started working...

Comment: @JudeDuran : Its reproducible on all the version of IE (8,9,10).

Comment: Still I am able to reproduce it in IE. Try to give different addresses. Sometime it comes sometime it not.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#input-geo").geocomplete().bind("click",function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Which version of IE are you checking in?

Comment: Its in all the version of IE including 8,9,10. 
Still same problem is coming after implementing your logic.

Comment: The above code will attach click event on input field not on "pac-container". I guess the event is propagating from "pac-container" itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem for IE and later on narrowed down to IE10 only.

To solve try adding

```
background-image:url(/none)
```

to the div elements that are not displaying. For some reason it works even if a non-existing image is inserted, so I used that.

It turns out that due to the fact that the dynamically created div was made transparent using progid:DXImageTransform, IE didn't capture events for said div.

I don't remember where I got this solution from. If I fond original link, I'll update the answer.